# Possible way to load and Print PDF on button Click using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

Could you please tell me the possible way to load and print pdf file that should work in all browers. Currently I am using iframe to show the file and then triggering print method but it's not working in IE.I searched a lot but none of the solution works.Please let me know any alternative approach to do this. Below is my sample code:-

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="pdfpoc.aspx.cs" Inherits="Game.pdfpoc" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function printpdf() 
{
    alert("pdfprint");
    var iframe = document.frames ? window.frames.frames["frPDF"] : document.getElementById("frPDF");
    var ifWin = iframe.contentWindow || iframe;
    try {

        ifWin.focus();
        ifWin.print();
    }
    catch (e) {
        window.print(false);
        //or when you get Invalid calling object error for IE9 and above
        //set the browser into IE8 compatibility mode will work
    }

    return false;
}
function changeSource() {
    console.log("change");
    var src = $("#frPDF").attr('src');
    console.log("src", src);

    if (src == "NCTP.pdf") {
        // $("#frPDF").attr('src', "NCTP1.pdf");
        url = "NCTP1.pdf";
    }
    else {
        //  $("#frPDF").attr('src', "NCTP.pdf");
        url = "NCTP.pdf";

    }
    console.log("Url" + url);
    var iframe = $('#frPDF')[0]; // reference to IFRAME element
    $.get(url, function () {
        iframe.src = url;
        $("#frPDF").load(function () {
            printpdf();
        });
        // $("#frPDF").trigger('onload');
    }).error(function () { alert('PDF not found'); });
    return false;
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
  <input type="button" value="Change Source" onclick="javascript:changeSource()" />
  <div> Its not the part of Iframè <br />
    IFRAME PDF: <br />
    <iframe id="frPDF" height="800" width="800" src="NB.pdf?a=1"></iframe>
  </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: unfortunately, for each browser - a different way of printing. For ie better use <embed id="frPDF" type="application/pdf" height="800" width="800" src="NB.pdf?a=1"></embed>

Answer (score 1):

For IE browser better use embed-tag for pdf, look at this(i replace your pdf source). it's work for me in IE 8+ and Chrome(and Opera ofc)

```
<input type="button" value="Change Source" name="btnChangeSource"  />
<div> Its not the part of Iframè <br />
    IFRAME PDF: <br />
    <embed id="frPDF" type="application/pdf" height="800" width="800" src="http://eurecaproject.eu/files/5013/9885/7113/example4.pdf"></embed>
 </div>
```

[**Solution for IE/Chrome/Opera**](http://jsfiddle.net/L6ma75wj/1/)

Comment: It's not loading the document in IE as well in chrome.I am using IE11.

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  function print(url)
  {
      var _this = this,
          iframeId = 'iframeprint',
          $iframe = $('iframe#iframeprint');
      $iframe.attr('src', url);

      $iframe.load(function() {
          _this.callPrint(iframeId);
      });
  }

  //initiates print once content has been loaded into iframe
  function callPrint(iframeId) {
      var PDF = document.getElementById(iframeId);
      PDF.focus();
      PDF.contentWindow.print();
  }
});
```